# Image works on docker but not on Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running a container based on a docker image. I do a simple `docker run` on docker, and it works fine.
However, the same image fails to be deployed on Kubernetes. There, I get this error:

```
 failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "proc" to rootfs at "/proc": SecureJoin /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/f2638afad33c8257b427adbb1cfd4f70d4c3108d95dd6ca69fb9f8de4663710e/rootfs//proc/: too many levels of symbolic links: unknown
```

I don't know why it works on docker, but not on Kubernetes. Any hints on how to solve this?

EDIT: Here is my deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: pixelfed
  name: pixelfed
  namespace: pixelfed
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pixelfed
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: pixelfed
    spec:
      topologySpreadConstraints:
        - maxSkew: 1
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
          whenUnsatisfiable: ScheduleAnyway
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              app: pixelfed
      containers:
        - name: pixelfed
          image: "ghcr.io/oculos/pixelfed"
          envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: secrets
          - configMapRef:
              name: pixelfed-settings
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
          - name: app-storage
            mountPath: /var/www/storage
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: app-storage
          nfs:
            server: 10.121.101.10
            path: /mnt/VM/k8s-data/pixelfed/app-storage
      restartPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerconfigjson-github-com
status: {}
```

Comment: Can you share your deployment yaml file(s)?

Comment: Just added it to the question @rock'nrolla